# Trying to drag and drop on a QFrame

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to allow a drop on a QFrame. I added these lines when creating the QFrame.

```
frame->setAcceptDrops(true);
qDebug()<<frame->acceptDrops();
```

The qDebug() returns "true" but when I drop a file or an item in the frame, nothing happens (no dropEvent).

The same code works fine when used with a QTreeWidget and QTableWidget.

So what am I doing wrong ? (The global idea is to be able to drag a QTreeWidgetitem and drop it on a QFrame)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `dropEvent()` to see what happens in there? You may have to reimplement it

Comment: Did you read the [drag and drop documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html)?